# MongoDB ObjectID query update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hey guys i need to write a mongodb query to update a document i,e need to increment a field in docuemnt by 1, so for that i am using $inc operation but i am facing trouble in matching the document's key with the data sent by frontend

my db looks like this

```
_id:ObjectID("5ed4a86126663308549f816b")
title:svsbsbsssf
description:wdwwdwd
category:Object
     _id:ObjectID("5ebc1144dde4f2974e209526")
     label:World after Covid
     category_id:1
     url:world-after-covid
     image:https://*****/assets/category-1590699874832.jpg
     value:1
```

so this category is an Object and i am getting my category id from frontend, after converting that to ObjectID, i tried to match it like

```
let doc = await req.db
      .collection("webinars")
      .updateOne({category._id: categoryID }, { $inc: { listingViews: 1 } });
```

but the filter inside updateOne gives me error somehow the syntax isnt correct i guess

the error is like

> Unexpected token, expected "," (17:26)
>
> 15 |     let doc = await req.db   16 |       .collection("webinars")
>
> > 17 |       .updateOne({category._id: categoryID }, { $inc: { listingViews: 1 } });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error in the `updateOne` filter object, the nested field path i.e `category._id` should be a string, something like this

```
 // Notice the quotes around category._id
 .updateOne({ "category._id": categoryID }, { $inc: { listingViews: 1 } });
```